# How can I export only the mnemonics from objdump (or any other program)?

Tags: disassembly, malware, objdump, assembly

I want to do an analysis with the mnemonics. I can export everything to text but I only need the last column. Any idea on how can I solve this?
In other words of this output of objdump (objdump -d file)

[image]

how can I only extract:

```
lea 
lea
push
nop
nop
lea
mov
lea
```

Comment: Looks to me like you copied and pasted the content of another question. This is not how our community work. And next time, pay attention to the sentences you copy, you asked for the "middle" column but mentioned you want the mnemonics (lea, push,...) which in the right column

Comment: @Megabeets He is absolutely right ... I am working on a project and I need to find out how to do it. where I saw her would not let me ask.

Comment: @WilberConcepciónLugo I edited the question, but please use your own words next time. Ask a friend to check your English if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting start address

```
objdump.exe -f calc.exe | grep start
start address 0x01012d6c
```

arguments passed to objdump via @File syntax where @File is disopt.txt 
containing arguments as below

```
C:\>cat disopt.txt
-d
-M intel
--no-show-raw-insn
--start-address         0x1012d6c
--stop-address          0x1012d8f
```

**C:>objdump.exe @disopt.txt c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe | sed 1,7d | awk "{print $2}"**

```
call
push
push
call
xor
mov
mov
lea
push
call
```

sed to remove first 7 lines
awk to print second column

actual disassembly without stripping lines and columns

```
C:\>objdump.exe @disopt.txt c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

01012d6c <.text+0x11d6c>:
 1012d6c:       call   0x1012abc
 1012d71:       push   0x58
 1012d73:       push   0x1012ee8
 1012d78:       call   0x100c768
 1012d7d:       xor    ebx,ebx
 1012d7f:       mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c],ebx
 1012d82:       mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],ebx
 1012d85:       lea    eax,[ebp-0x68]
 1012d88:       push   eax
 1012d89:       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x100114c
```

Edit To answer the comment about two mnemonic (the prefix operands like lock  rep , repz , repnz etc )

```
:\>objdump --no-show-raw-insn -d calc.exe | awk "{ if($2==\"lock\") {print $2,$3} }"
lock ja
lock (bad)
lock add
lock xadd
:\>objdump --no-show-raw-insn -d calc.exe | awk "{ if($2==\"rep\") {print $2,$3} }"
rep stos
rep movsl
```

Comment: ok, but how to know the address of the entry point to start disassembling? --start-address   ??

Comment: and the opcodes that are two words (lock in) in this way only "lock" is extracted?

Comment: I want to execute the same file yours disopt.txt, but in the argument "--start-address" is the address of the entry point ...                       objdump @disopt.txt c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe | awk "{ if($2==\"lock\") {print $2,$3} else print $2 }"    C:\>cat disopt.txt
-d
--no-show-raw-insn
--start-address         ????

Comment: objdump -f  bin  shows the entry point use that as i already answered

Answer (score 1):

Columns in objdump output are commonly separated by tabs, so something like the following should help:

```
objdump -d program | sed  '/[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t/!d' | cut -f 3 | sed 's/ .*$//'
```

The first sed invocation removes lines not containing at least two tab characters (i.e. labels and other non-code output), cut returns the third tab-separated column of the remaining output and the final sed gets rid of the first space character and the rest of each line, i.e. all text after the opcode.

(This question might have been better suited for the unix stackexchange community)

Comment: that command line and it still does not work for me, can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any errors? What OS are you using?

Comment: There is something wrong in that sequence with the "sed". Windows 10.Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, however I ran this on Linux (Debian 9 on x64) with GNU objdump (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28, sed (GNU sed) 4.4 and cut (GNU coreutils) 8.26. However, I don't think any of these options are exotic. Can you upload the output you get from objdump somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelEngel just replace the single quote with double quote should work as is in windows